# Arrays K&R 1.6 chars?

Tags: c, arrays, char, integer

on page 23 in the K&R second edition, there is some code

```
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
       ++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

It goes on. My question is, why do the integers have the ' on each side?
and what is the c-'0'?

Comment: `0` is not same as `'0'`.

Comment: Yeah but the book did a very poor job of explain them. Or maybe I just did a very poor job of understanding them :/

Comment: it is to check if value of `c`  is ascii code of a digit

Comment: You got to page 23 and don't know why character literals have single quotes around them? Go back to page 1 and start reading again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the code is to convert the **characters** `'0'...'9'` into the corresponding **integer** values `0...9`. C does **not** guarantee that the characters representing decimal digits have any particular value, but it **does** guarantee that they are consecutive and in the correct order. The subtraction above will always give you the correct integer value.

There is no similar guarantee for any other character in C.

#### References

The ISO 9899:1999 Standard (aka C99) says:

> The values of the members of the execution character set are implementation-defined. ...
>
> A byte with all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string. ...
>
> the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

Exactly the same wording is found in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), which was the final public draft of the current standard (C11).

Not much else is said about the values of, or relationship between characters.

Answer (score 2):

`'0'` is a character. It has the integer value 48. `'9'` has the value 57. The value of `c - '0'` is equal to `c - 48`, and will be the integer value of the corresponding character. `'0'` will be `0`, `'1'` will be `1`, etc.

Comment: So you could just as easily use 0 and 9 instead for the same purpose? Because ASCII 0-9 starts at 48 and goes up to 57 for 9, and the code was finding if c was '0'to'9' but it could just find 0 to 9?

Comment: @Erik: "It has the integer value 48" is very likely to be true, but it ain't necessarily so.

Comment: @OVER9000: No, because 0 and 9 have the integer values 0 and 9, not 48 and 57 ;)

Comment: @NisseEngström: K&R. 2nd edition. From 1988. Yes, It is necessarily so ;) (OK, then, not necessarily, but for all practical purposes).

Answer (score 1):

`'0'` is a `char`, i.e. a character. Every character is internally represented by an integer. See [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). For example, `'0'` has the integer value `48`.